# JiraTestResultReporter.JiraReporter aborted due to exception error in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jira-plugin

I configured `JIRA` plugin with `Jenkins`, I'm getting this error after build get completed. Could anyone explain how can I fix this issue with explanation.

```
Jenkins ver. 1.580

JIRA plugin 1.39

JiraTestResultReporter plugin 1.0.4

ERROR: Publisher JiraTestResultReporter.JiraReporter aborted due to exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getTestResultAction()Lhudson/tasks/test/AbstractTestResultAction;
    at JiraTestResultReporter.JiraReporter.perform(JiraReporter.java:105)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:734)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:683)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1770)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25140

The bug itself was fixed a long time ago in the GitHub repository, but a change has not yet been released.

Once a newer version than 1.0.4 has been released, this should be resolved.