# Jenkins Jira Test Result Reporter ERROR

Tags: jenkins, jira

facing the same issue already asked over here [JiraTestResultReporter.JiraReporter aborted due to exception error in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26257627/jiratestresultreporter-jirareporter-aborted-due-to-exception-error-in-jenkins)

Appreciate any hints...

```
[JiraTestResultReporter] [INFO] Examining test results...
ERROR: Publisher 'Jira Test Result Reporter' aborted due to exception: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getTestResultAction()Lhudson/tasks/test/AbstractTestResultAction;
    at JiraTestResultReporter.JiraReporter.perform(JiraReporter.java:105)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:726)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:671)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1769)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: If this question has been asked before, please follow up on this topic.

Comment: yes, I wanted to add my follow up enquiry over that topic which is not answered yet - but add comments didn't allowed me as a new entrant without much reputation :) hence created a new query. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a "follow up", it's an exact duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Christopher for answering over there after my duplicate follow-up thread.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is also the same or very related with [JiraTestResultReporter.JiraReporter aborted due to exception error in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26257627/jiratestresultreporter-jirareporter-aborted-due-to-exception-error-in-jenkins?s=2|0.0943) The steps below that I have followed to solve the issue has been inspired on the mentioned thread.

I obtained a functional hpi plugin compiling a branch from Github repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/gglentini/JiraTestResultReporter-plugin.git --branch unirest
```

Compiling wit:

```
mvn package -DskipTest
```

And manually installing target/JiraTestResultReporter.hpi in Jenkins.

The buildings after restarting Jenkins did not have the error.